# Pointer to an instance of a function template

Tags: c++, linux, templates, gcc

I want to use the thunk function template to pass it around to pthread_create and stuff like that.

I would expect the compiler to instantiate the function with the given parameters, all the info is there, and then use the typedef as a function ptr to pass to those functions.

```
#include <string>
class ServerImpl{
    public:
        ServerImpl(std::string host, int port);
        void run();

};


template<typename T,void (T::*mem_fn)()>
void *thunk(void *obj) {
    (static_cast<T*>(obj)->*mem_fn)();
    return 0;
}

typedef void *(*Function) (void);
Function fun = (Function)&thunk<ServerImpl,&ServerImpl::run>;
fun();
```

**JUST CHANGED IT**

See, with this I get a linker error, which is what it brought me to the previous one. Omit the fact that I should be passing an object.

```
Server.o: In function `ServerImpl::ServerImpl(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int)':
Server.cpp:(.text+0x11f): undefined reference to `void* thunk<ServerImpl, &(ServerImpl::run())>(void*)'
```

Comment: Irrelevant of the issue, for threads, use Boost.Thread or C++11 standard library threading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`thunk` is a function template. How can you use `typedef` on it? It doesn't make sense. It is not a *type*. You can apply `typedef` only on types.

You should do this:

```
 ServerImpl *arg = new ServerImpl(); //why do I use new?
 pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &thunk<ServerImpl,&ServerImpl::run>, arg);
```

Your arguments to `pthread_create` are wrong. It takes 4 arguments, not 2.

#### Why did I use new?

I created an instance of `ServerImpl` using `new`, because the instance has to exist even if the function in which you created the thread have returned. If I don't create the instance using `new`, and instead use local variable, then the code invoke undefined behavior, if the function returned but the thread continue running.

---

Reply to your edit:

```
Function fun = (Function)&thunk<ServerImpl,&ServerImpl::run>;
fun();
```

This is wrong. Because `thunk` takes one argument. So you should be doing this instead:

```
Function fun = (Function)&thunk<ServerImpl,&ServerImpl::run>;
fun(new ServerImpl); //pass an argument
```

The member function `run` is invoked on this argument which you passed.

Comment: hey, pthread_create was an example, not really doing that, but see my update, just trying to call the function fails at link time.

Comment: Nono, check the typedef, I am casting away the parameter to pass it through other signatures and then I'll cast it back to receive the parameter. In any case that should never stop the compilation or link time, the compiler cannot find the thunk instantiation, somehow.

Comment: @ArkaitzJimenez: That is wrong. You cannoft do that. It is UB.

Comment: @ArkaitzJimenez: See this : http://ideone.com/V6q9m . You should be doing like this. Just note that for simplicity I made the constructor of `ServerImpl` parameterless.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty plain. That's like trying to do

```
void f() { }
typedef f blah;
```

or

```
int a;
typedef a something;
```

You'll just have to do

```
pthread_create(&thread_id, &thunk<ServerImpl, &ServerImpl::run>);
```

Or if you like:

```
auto threadproc = &thunk<ServerImpl, &ServerImpl::run>;
pthread_create(&thread_id, threadproc);
```

And, on the stylistic side, please use spaces after each comma in argument lists :)

Comment: Yeah, that compiles but then I find linker errors with thunk: `Server.cpp:(.text+0x140): undefined reference to `void* thunk<ServerImpl, &(ServerImpl::run())>(void*)'`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's the compiler is trying to tell you , but the signature of `thunk` doesn't use any of the template type, how are you expecting the compiler to guess it ?

There pthread_create is expecting a function not a type (typedef fun define a type, not a function)

Comment: No, it's not that. Function name is not a type, so you cannot create a typedef alias for it.